# Why is DPDK forwarding performance lower in small packets?

Tags: performance, dpdk

I have read this report "Intel DPDK Performance Report" at "http://fast.dpdk.org/doc/perf/Intel_DPDK_R16_11_NIC_performance_report.pdf".

I have found that DPDK's performance with small packets(e.g 64Bytes) is lower than bigger packets(e.g 128/256 Bytes). The bigger ones offen own 100% wire speed. But the smaller one only have about 60% wire speed.

Why? Just because small packets will cause frenquency operations? What is the limitations?

Comment: I have no idea what DPDK is. However, in *all* communications systems a packet is a unit containing some form of header (i.e. metadata) and the actual payload (i.e. the data you actually send). Obviously the smaller the payload the higher the overhead due to the headers (in terms of bit/s sent). Moreover handling a packet required reading the header, understanding it and doing something with it (e.g. drop the packet, forward it to somebody else, send it to an application), so obviously the more packets, the more time spent looking at headers to send the same amount of data.

Answer (score 2):

The limitation is the number of packets per second (PPS) DPDK can process on a given system. Each packet must be received, processed and sent back to the wire. DPDK does not copy the content of packets, so the processing time for 64 byte packet is more or less the same as for the 1500 byte packet.

So for the given performance report the limit is 36.09 millions packets per second (Mpps) for the smallest 64 byte packets. Which it is still not enough to reach 100% of the wire speed.

In its turn, the number of packets per second a system can process depends on NIC, CPU, memory bandwidth, cache size etc etc.